# The local uninitialized pointer variable of linked list contains the same address as the list head

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am studying linked list and try to understand pointers, their own physical addresses and the address they point to.  I write code for printing the list and find a strange phenomenon just like the title describes. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int num;
    struct Node *next;
};

void addNode(Node*&, int);

void printList(Node*);

int main() {
    Node *a = NULL;

    addNode(a, 1);
    addNode(a, 2);
    addNode(a, 3);

    cout << "After adding three nodes, a contains " << a << ", a locates at " << &a << endl;
    cout << "a->next contains " << a->next << endl;
    cout << "a->num = " << a->num << endl;
    cout << endl;

    printList(a);

    cout << "After printing, a contains " << a << ", a locates at " << &a << endl;
    cout << "a->next contains " << a->next << endl;
    cout << "a->num = " << a->num << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void addNode(Node *&A, int i) {
    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->num = i;
    temp->next = A;
    A = temp;
}

void printList(Node *A) {
    cout << "1. printList: A contains " << A << ", A locates at " << &A << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Node *current;
    cout << "2. current contains " << current << " (uninitialized), current locates at " << &current << endl;
    //cout << current->next << endl;
    cout << endl;

    current = A;
    cout << "3. After being assigned by A, current contains " << current << ", current locates at " << &current << endl;
    cout << endl;

    while(true) {
        if(current == NULL) break;

        cout << "num is " << current->num << endl;
        current = current->next;
        cout << "After being assigned by next, current contains " << current << ", current locates at " << &current << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "End of the list" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is the result:

> After adding three nodes, a contains 0x2822a98, a locates at 0x6bfebc
>   a->next contains 0x2822a88 a->num = 3
>
> 1. printList: A contains 0x2822a98, A locates at 0x6bfea0
> 2. current contains 0x6bfebc (uninitialized), current locates at 0x6bfe8c
> 3. After being assigned by A, current contains 0x2822a98, current locates at 0x6bfe8c
>
> num is 3 After being assigned by next, current contains 0x2822a88,
>   current locates at 0x6bfe8c
>
> num is 2 After being assigned by next, current contains 0x2822a78,
>   current locates at 0x6bfe8c
>
> num is 1 After being assigned by next, current contains 0, current
>   locates at 0x6bfe8c
>
> End of the list
>
> After printing, a contains 0x2822a98, a locates at 0x6bfebc a->next
>   contains 0x2822a88 a->num = 3

Note, the item 2: current contains 0x6bfebc.  The "0x6bfebc" is just identical with a's address, which is displayed at the the first line. But I think an uninitialized pointer variable should point to a random address.  To avoid from coincidence, I try to reopen the program and restart my computer, but every time it is just locked to the address of a. Can somebody explain what really happen inside.  Thanks.

For being more readable, I add a screenshot at the end.  Hope it helps.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpmQX.png)

Comment: Have you try to debug your code with `gdb`!

Comment: Not yet. Actually I am not familiar with C++ debug. I usually print out what I want using `cout`.

Comment: If you really want to dig deeper memory allocation principle, try `g++ -S hello.cpp -o hello.s` ..

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable is *undefined behavior*. Anything that happens then should be considered just garbage. Not random, **garbage**.

Comment: Did you got this type of output always or just once. If once can ignore it as co-incidence

Comment: @PasserBy Yep, I think so.  Thanks.